# Github API: determine if user or org

Tags: github-api

Given the URL https://github.com/foo/bar, I want to be able to get all the repos for foo. If foo is a user, I need to call `api.repos.getForUser({username: 'foo'})` and if an org, I'll need to call `api.repos.getForOrg({org: 'foo'})`.

My problem is: how can I tell if "foo" is an org or a user?

Right now, I "solve" it in the costly way of trying to get an org called "foo", if I got it, I try to get its repos; if I end up getting an exception (I use promises) and if the code of the exception is "404", I assume "foo" is a user, and try to get user repos.

This is obviously inefficient, and has the side effect of adding calls that may trigger rate limit.

Is there an easier way to know whether "foo" is a user or an org?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As we all know, handling exceptions is costly. So instead of trying to get an org and handling the `404`, you could instead look at the `type` property of the response to `https://api.github.com/users/<username>` in order to determine if the "user" is a user or organization and then proceed accordingly.

For example a call to my GitHub user API https://api.github.com/users/raghav710 returns

```
{
  "login": "raghav710",
  ...
  "type": "User",
  ...
}
```

And a call to an organization like https://api.github.com/users/Microsoft returns

```
 {
   "login": "Microsoft",
   ...
   "type": "Organization",
   ...
}
```

**Update: Doing it in a single call**

I understand that you are already trying to access a URL `https://github.com/<user or organization>/<repo name>` and therein trying to get all the repos of that user or organization.

A suggestion is, instead of trying to do a GET on the above link, you could do a GET on `https://api.github.com/repos/<user or organization>/<repo name>`

For example doing a GET on https://api.github.com/repos/Microsoft/vscode

Gives

```
{
    "id": 41881900,
    "name": "vscode",
    "full_name": "Microsoft/vscode",
    "owner": {
        "login": "Microsoft",
        "id": 6154722,
        ...
        "type": "Organization",
    },
    "private": false,
    "html_url": "https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode",
    ...
}
```

As you can see the familiar `type` field is available under the owner key. You can use this to decide your next call

Comment: Excellent! Somehow missed that field's significance. I wonder if there's a way to do this without the extra call? Although this definitely makes my code smoother :)

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy that would be an interesting exercise. Let me check if I can find something

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy I think I've found a way to do that. Updated the answer accordingly

Comment: I don't think you can call exception handling "costly" compared to do HTTP requests

Comment: @Bergi I meant that compared to the OPs initial idea of a HTTP call + exception handling an approach that uses HTTP call + a conditional would be cheaper. Feel free to correct me in case i am wrong :)

Comment: @raghav710 Exactly that difference is totally negligible because of the large overhead of the HTTP call.

Answer (score 1):

So even if there's an API call to differentiate, you'll still need that call to determine whether it's a user or not.

Considering the fact that most repositories *should* belong to users, why don't you reverse the checks? Try to retrieve the user repository, if that fails get the organization repository.

In addition, I'd cache as much information as necessary. Don't retrieve everything in real time while users use your tool. Many things won't change that often, if they're even able to be changed.

Comment: Agreed - I'm working on a caching mechanism as we speak. Started with files, will move to DB. MongoDB seems like an overkill. I wish there was agood NoSQL Sqlite :)